# What is the meaning of "to Max's Donnie"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the movie *Game Night (2018)*, Ryan says about Max's brother, Brooks:

> Ryan: He's like the **Mark Wahlberg to Max's Donnie**.
>
> Annie (says to Max): Well...Which is a huge compliment because Donnie
>   was fucking great in The Sixth Sense, wasn't he?

What is the meaning of "to Max's Donnie"?

I didn't understand the comparison, I know Mark Wahlberg is good looking actor and Sixth Sense is movie.

Comment: Michael Harvey has given you the main answer, but a bit of pop culture history might be relevant. Donnie Wahlberg was originally the more famous brother, as part of the boy band New Kids on the Block. Later, Mark became even more famous as a model and musical act, then as an actor. So, Ryan says Max is overshadowed by Brooks similar to the way Donnie is overshadowed by Mark, but Annie, Max's wife, finds the comparison of Max to Donnie complimentary, given Donnie's widely praised performance in *The Sixth Sense*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you wish to say that the relationship of two people (A and B) is, in some way, like the relationship of two other people (X and Y), you can use a possessive form for Y when comparing B to Y. Usually X and Y are famous or at least known to the listener. Ryan is saying that Brooks' relationship to his brother Max is like Mark Wahlberg's relationship to *his* older brother Donnie Wahlberg. My mother is like Hitler to my father's Goering. You are like Bluto to my Popeye. She is like Cleopatra to your Julius Caesar.